# Kotlin Common Dialog Not Showing

Tags: android, kotlin

Unable to showing Common Dialog.I am new in Kotlin.Does any guys meet this issue?

I have tried

```
class CommonStaticClass {


    fun showCommonPopUp(activity: Context, msg: String,drawable: Int): Dialog {

        val metrics     = activity.resources.displayMetrics
        val dev_width   = metrics.widthPixels
        val dev_height  = metrics.heightPixels

        val dialogCommon = Dialog(activity)
        dialogCommon.window.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT))
        dialogCommon.window.requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
        dialogCommon.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_alert)
        dialogCommon.setCancelable(false)
        dialogCommon.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)
        dialogCommon.window.setLayout((dev_width* 85)/ 100, (dev_height* 25) / 100)

        val tv_headerObj = dialogCommon.findViewById(R.id.txt_header) as TextView
        val img_smileOBJ = dialogCommon.findViewById(R.id.img_smile) as ImageView
        img_smileOBJ.setImageResource(drawable)
        tv_headerObj.text = msg + ""
        dialogCommon.show()

        return dialogCommon
    }
}
```

Kotlin class

```
val commonDIALOG= commonDialogOBJ!!.showCommonPopUp(getActivity()!!,"Your session has expired. Please log in",R.drawable.ic_sad)
commonDIALOG.show()
```

I have declared

```
 private var commonDialogOBJ : CommonStaticClass? = null
commonDialogOBJ              =  CommonStaticClass()
```

Answer (score 0):

Its working for me.

take for example my xml

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/txt_header"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Then

```
val commonDialogOBJ: CommonStaticClass by lazy { CommonStaticClass() }

commonDialogOBJ.showCommonPopUp(this, "Hello world");
```

and your class code is all perfect. But everything will be transparent